# Determining azimuth of continuous polyline segment

Tags: qgis, geometry, azimuth

I have a polyline which represent the river bank of a particular section of a river drawn based on Satellite imagery. As you can see in the picture, it is drawn in red color. I have also a vertices which are generated from this polyline (yellow circle in picture). I want to measure azimuth in decimal degree with 6 precision of every line segment of this polyline, which will be added to the attribute table and can shown as labels in middle of the line segment. How can I proceed to do with QGIS?

[image: Brahmaputra River Bank in Mymensingh, Bangladesh,]

Answer (score 3):

Try **Explode Lines** tool (in `Processing Toolbox > Vector geometry`) to extract segments out of your red line layer.

Then open the `Layer Properties > Label` of the produced `Exploded` layer and give an expression:

```
degrees(azimuth(start_point($geometry), end_point($geometry)))
```

[image]

You need the labels, not the exploded line segments. To hide the `Exploded` line from showing on the map, set its `Symbology` to `No symbols`.

[image]